# Free/Busy support for Domino

Tags: lotus-domino, activesync

I would like to implement Free/Busy for domino accounts in my iOS Client using active sync commands, but I'm not sure what is the XML (web XML structure) for request and response.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're looking for since you don't detailed what you've archive what you need...

Comment: @Pavan, welcome to StackOverflow.  Things work best when you follow up on a question you've asked.  Assuming your question was answered, please accept one of the answers below.  If your question hasn't been answered, please explain why.  For example, you can edit the original question or add a comment to one of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

you may take a look at the project in the openNTF:

[Domino Freebusy Service Developer Guide](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/783A19E01A5CC35886257C1A00730CCD/$file/Domino%20Freebusy%20Service.pdf)

part of [XPages Extension Library](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/documentation/783A19E01A5CC35886257C1A00730CCD)

This project (I didn't try it) could answer to http request you should invoke it from ios.

Answer (score 0):

Register to IBM partner Program as isv.
There will be help you, i think for free.

https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_com_jnw_index